# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I get this error whenever I run my program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shepard/Desktop/Gradebook.py", line 51, in <module>
    qs.CreateDb()
  File "C:/Users/Shepard/Desktop/Gradebook.py", line 14, in CreateDb
    self.cursor.exeute(query)
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'exeute'
```

This makes me beleive that my problems are in:

```
 def CreateDb(self):
        query = """CREATE TABLE questions
                 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Question TEXT, Answer1 TEXT, Answer2 TEXT, Answer3 TEXT, Answer4 TEXT, CorrectAnswer TEXT)"""
        self.cursor.exeute(query)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
```

either in that, or in

```
def AddQuestion(self, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4):
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO questions
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", [None, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer])
self.connection.commit()
```

Is 'execute' not a valid attribute? If so, what should I use? I'm a little over my head in this one. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It' doesn't say "execute" it says "exeute". You misspelled it.

Comment: Really, is this not a simple TYPO

Answer (score 1):

There  word 'exeute' in your function for CreateDB,

```
self.cursor.exeute(query)
```

it should be ‘execute’. I have made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the possible commands for both the connection and cursor:

```
print("Connection functions:",dir(sqlite3.connect('::memory::')))
print("\n\n")
print("Cursor functions:",dir(sqlite3.connect('::memory::').cursor()))
```

Check that things are spelled right and that you don't mix connection and cursor.